# $f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(g_i(x)-g_{i+1}(x))g_i(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> $X=Y=[0,1]$ with $\mu$ and $\nu$ both being Lebesgue measure. Let $g_i$ be continuous functions with support in $(1/(i+1), 1/i)$ such that $\int_0^1 g_i(x)dx=1 $ . Let $$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(g_i(x)-g_{i+1}(x))g_i(y)$$

I want to compute that

> (1) $\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx=0$

I try to write $$\int_0^1 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(g_i(x)-g_{i+1}(x))g_i(y)dx=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_0^1 (g_i(x)-g_{i+1}(x))g_i(y)dx$$
How to rewrite $\int_0^1$ in terms of $\int_{1/(i+1)}^{1/i}$?

> (2) $\int_0^1\int_0^1\vert f(x,y)\vert dxdy=\infty$

I feel like we can write:
$\int_0^1\vert f(x,y)\vert dx=\sum_{n} \int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n} \vert g_n(x) g_n(y)\vert dx$. So 
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\vert f(x,y)\vert dxdy\geq \int_0^1\sum_{n} \int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n} \vert g_n(x) g_n(y)\vert dxdy \geq \sum_{n} \int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n} \vert g_n(x)\vert dx\int_0^1 \vert g_n(y)\vert dy =\infty$$

Comment: Okay, it goes through as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $y\in[0,1]$, find a $k$ such that $y\in(1/(k+1),1/k]$, then 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dx&=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(g_{i}(x)-g_{i+1}(x))g_{i}(y)dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}(g_{k}(x)-g_{k+1}(x))g_{k}(y)dx\\
&=g_{k}(y)\left(\int_{0}^{1}g_{k}(x)dx-\int_{0}^{1}g_{k+1}(x)dx\right)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}

On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}|f(x,y)|dxdy\\
&\geq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int_{1/(i+1)}^{1/i}\int_{1/(i+1)}^{1/i}|f(x,y)|dxdy\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int_{1/(i+1)}^{1/i}\int_{1/(i+1)}^{1/i}|g_{i}(x)||g_{i}(y)|dxdy\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{1/(i+1)}^{1/i}|g_{i}(x)|dx\right)\left(\int_{1/(i+1)}^{1/i}|g_{i}(y)|dy\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{1}|g_{i}(x)|dx\right)\left(\int_{0}^{1}|g_{i}(y)|dy\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{1}|g_{i}(x)|dx\right)^{2}\\
&\geq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left|\int_{0}^{1}g_{i}(x)dx\right|^{2}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}1\\
&=\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: I feel like $g_{k+1}$ is zero since its support is $(1/(k+2), 1/(k+1))$?

Comment: We control the $y$, the $x$ varies in the integral.

Comment: I mean $g_{k+1}(x)$.

Comment: The reasoning is still the same, the $x$ varies within $[0,1]$, it is just that $y$ being control by $(1/(k+1),1/k]$.

Comment: I made the mistake on typo, I wanted to say $y$, so that's why I got downvoted.

Comment: Never mind, I'm an idiot.

Comment: Why the second line of "On the other hand,
" is $\geq$?

Comment: If you see all those little boxes $[1/(i+1),1/i]\times[1/(i+1),1/i]$, their union are not the full $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, you may draw a graph.

Comment: So you mean $\int_0^1\geq \sum_n \int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n}$?

Comment: Not really, it is that $\displaystyle\iint_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\geq\sum_{i}\iint_{[1/(i+1),1/i]\times[1/(i+1),1/i]}$.

Comment: But how about the $\int_0^1 $ and $\sum \int _{1/(n+1)}^{1/n}$? Are they same?

Comment: The trick is to see the support, so that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\cdots=\int_{1/(i+1)}^{1/i}\cdots$.

Comment: @user284331 I mean $\int_0^1\vert f(x,y)\vert dx=\sum_{n} \int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n} \vert g_n(x) g_n(y)\vert dx$

Comment: First of all, I tacitly use Tonelli to look at the whole square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, and if you draw a graph, the diagonal little squares $[1/(i+1),1/i]\times[1/(i+1),1/i]$ are nonoverlapping and their union is less than the whole square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, so the double integral on the whole square is greater than the sum of the double integrals of of those diagonal little squares, and then I used Tonelli again to split them.

Comment: @user284331 Yes, I know your method. But I have another method. Do you think it is right?